# Transforming coordinate system for 3D points

Tags: coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have a set of **3D points** (let's say 10 points created randomly with x,y,z values between 0-100) and I want to **transform** them **to another coordinate system**. I also have the rotation (**R**) and translation (**t**) matrices which will perform the transformation of the coordinate system.
My question is this: if my initial set of points is **X** (10x3), then **Y = R*X.T + t**  is the matrix containing the coordinates of the transformed points but still in respect to my initial coordinate system, right? If so, how can I find the new coordinates of the points in respect to their **new** coordinate system?